# Tail the last 5 lines, over-writing the last 5 displayed lines when more are added?

Tags: command-line, tail

When using `tail -f` to display the last few lines of a file, how can I make it only ever display 5 lies, overwriting previous lines when the file is added to?

Comment: A simple solution is to write into a terminal window with 5 lines.

Comment: @sododus What about a convoluted solution?

Comment: Please explain what you need, how you intend to use it?

Comment: I'm using tail -f on a linode server. The process is active so I get a page of text every second, and it seems to hang a lot. If I could just view the last 5 lines, that would be enough to let me know that the process is running ok.

Comment: `tail` outputs continuously. It doesn't clear the the terminal and cannot overwrite already existing lines. I'd say what you're seeking cannot be done, at least not with `tail` itself

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to watch the file "file-to-be-watched", the following may do the trick:

```
watch -n 1 tail -5 file-to-be-watched
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you working at a text mode console, or for example via ssh from a desktop environment?

I made a small demo with `date` which uses `xterm`.

```
xterm -geometry 60x6 -e bash -c 'while true; do dat=$(date "+%H:%M:%S");echo "Hello $dat";echo "world $dat";echo "alias $dat";echo "blank $dat";echo "      $dat"; sleep 1;done'|tail -f
```

You should be able to replace the while loop with your program, that prints lines every second